# Arduino Uno RFID-RC522 won't scan any card or tag

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, voltage-level, rfid

So I bought a RFID-RC522 module with a blue tag and a white card, and I searched for tutorials and found this [**library**](https://github.com/ljos/MFRC522) that I used it.

and here is my code :

```
#include <MFRC522.h>
#include <SPI.h>

#define SAD 10
#define RST 9

MFRC522 nfc(SAD, RST);

void setup() {
  SPI.begin();
  // Read a fast as possible. There is a limit for how long we are
  // allowed to read from the tags.
  Serial.begin(115200);

  Serial.println("Looking for MFRC522.");
  nfc.begin();

  // Get the firmware version of the RFID chip
  byte version = nfc.getFirmwareVersion();
  if (! version) {
    Serial.print("Didn't find MFRC522 board.");
    while(1); //halt
  }

  Serial.print("Found chip MFRC522 ");
  Serial.print("Firmware ver. 0x");
  Serial.print(version, HEX);
  Serial.println(".");
}

byte keyA[6] = {0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, };
byte keyB[6] = {0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, };

void loop() {
  byte status;
  byte data[MAX_LEN];
  byte serial[5];
  int i, j, pos;

  // Send a general request out into the aether. If there is a tag in
  // the area it will respond and the status will be MI_OK.
  status = nfc.requestTag(MF1_REQIDL, data);

  if (status == MI_OK) {
    Serial.println("Tag detected.");
    Serial.print("Type: ");
    Serial.print(data[0], HEX);
    Serial.print(", ");
    Serial.println(data[1], HEX);

    // calculate the anti-collision value for the currently detected
    // tag and write the serial into the data array.
    status = nfc.antiCollision(data);
    memcpy(serial, data, 5);

    Serial.println("The serial nb of the tag is:");
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      Serial.print(serial[i], HEX);
      Serial.print(", ");
    }
    Serial.println(serial[3], HEX);

    // Select the tag that we want to talk to. If we don't do this the
    // chip does not know which tag it should talk if there should be
    // any other tags in the area..
    nfc.selectTag(serial);

    // Assuming that there are only 64 blocks of memory in this chip.
    for (i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
      // Try to authenticate each block first with the A key.
      status = nfc.authenticate(MF1_AUTHENT1A, i, keyA, serial);
      if (status == MI_OK) {
        Serial.print("Authenticated block nb. 0x");
        Serial.print(i, HEX);
        Serial.println(" with key A.");
        // Reading block i from the tag into data.
        status = nfc.readFromTag(i, data);
        if (status == MI_OK) {
          // If there was no error when reading; print all the hex
          // values in the data.
          for (j = 0; j < 15; j++) {
            Serial.print(data[j], HEX);
            Serial.print(", ");
          }
          Serial.println(data[15], HEX);
        } else {
          Serial.println("Read failed.");
        }
      } else {
        // If we could not authenticate with the A key, we will try
        // the B key.
        status = nfc.authenticate(MF1_AUTHENT1B, i, keyB, serial);
        if (status == MI_OK) {
          Serial.print("Authenticated block nb. 0x");
          Serial.print(i, HEX);
          Serial.println(" with key B.");
          status = nfc.readFromTag(i, data);
          if (status == MI_OK) {
            for (j = 0; j < 15; j++) {
              Serial.print(data[j], HEX);
              Serial.print(", ");
            }
            Serial.println(data[15], HEX);
          } else {
            Serial.println("Read failed.");
          }
        } else {
          Serial.print("Access denied at block nb. 0x");
          Serial.println(i, HEX);
        }
      }
    }

    // Stop the tag and get ready for reading a new tag.
    nfc.haltTag();
  }
  delay(2000);
}
```

and I connected the module like this :

```
===================================
|   RFID-RC522   |  Arduino Uno   |
___________________________________
|      SDA       |       10       |
|      SCK       |       13       |
|      MOSI      |       11       |
|      MISOI     |       12       |
|      RQ        |     Skipped    |
|      GND       |       GND      |
|      RST       |        9       |
|      3.3V      |       3.3V     |
===================================
```

and when I virify and uplaod the code, the RFID-RC522 module turned the light D1 to On (red light)
and in the serial it show :

```
Looking for MFRC522.
Didn't find MFRC522 board.
```

and when i try to scan the card or the tag nothing happened in the serial, I searched in google and i found that Arduino uno 3.3V pin is too weak, so i changed the 3.3V to 5V, and click in reset button of arduino uno board and check the serial and it showed :

```
Looking for MFRC522.
Found chip MFRC522 Firmware ver. 0xFF.
```

But still not scaning the tag or the card *(also tried another tag and another card that i bought them from the same seller and still not working)*

any help please, and thanks

Comment: use an external power supply that can deliver the necessary current ... please review the RFID-RC522 module datasheet for minimum power requirement

Comment: What is external power? a battery ? or resistor... and thanks for reply

Comment: a resistor is not a power supply ... do not use the Arduino to supply power... use anything that is able provide the required voltage to the RFID reader at the necessary current level ... 5 Vdc power supply is probably the most suitable